# Should questions like this one be closed for lack of detail?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

[What's difference between these?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/91141/whats-difference-between-these)

This question has been closed as a pure translation question, me myself among the people who cast closevotes. The reason for closure is stated as follows

> Questions asking for translations, transcriptions or proofreading are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not to provide a bulk translation service nor to proofread your translations or transcriptions. See: We don't do translations.

I actually voted to close for a different reason:

> Needs details or clarity
> This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Most questions like this one seem to have been closed as translation requests, which I think is totally reasonable. But I do wonder if "lack of detail" would be a better close reason. For example, the question at issue asks about the difference in meaning between several sentences, and it would be an answerable and on-topic post with more input from the questioner, such as what OP thinks, what exactly OP understands and doesn't understand, what research they have done. Had the question included these details, it wouldn't have been closed. That's why I thought "needs details or clarity" was a better reason.

What do folks think?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for very late response. Forgot to look at Meta recently.

I think you are right that this should be a 'details of clarity' closure rather than a 'translation request' closure. However, I think voting to close based on details and clarity is useless unless the voter adds a comment suggesting what should be expected of the OP. It looks like this person was a new user who got their first question closed. They have no idea why and didn't bother to come back again. Rather sad really. On the occasions when I use this vote I add a comment, wait a day or so to give the OP chance to respond, and then cast my vote if they have not improved the question.